# How do I count cells with in a range in excel with specific value that has a comment using vba or formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I need help on this. I'm doing a report and inserting comments on cells. How do I count cells with in a range in excel with specific value that has a comment using vba or formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.  It loops through each cell you pass in the range and checks if there is a comment.  If so, it adds it to a counter.  This is probably going to be pretty expensive if used on large range, but it should at least get you started:

Add to a regular module:

```
Function CommentCounter(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim currentComment As String


    For Each cell In rng
        On Error Resume Next
        currentComment = cell.Comment.Text
        If Len(currentComment) > 0 Then counter = counter + 1
        currentComment = ""
    Next cell

    CommentCounter = counter
End Function
```

Just saw the part about having a specific value AND a comment. This should get you going:

```
Function CommentCounter(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim currentComment As String
    Dim specificValue As String

    specificValue = "Something Specific"


    For Each cell In rng
        On Error Resume Next
        currentComment = cell.Comment.Text
        If cell.Value = specificValue And Len(currentComment) > 0 Then counter = counter + 1
        currentComment = ""
    Next cell

    CommentCounter = counter
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;"comment")
```

Where A:A specifies that you want to examine the whole column of A. Instead of A:A, you could also use A1:A3, which means examine A1, A2 and A3.

EDIT:

If you want to count the cells with comments (not with the word "comment"), I would suggest to do the following:

```
=COUNT(A1:A3) - COUNTBLANK(A1:A3)
```

Comment: i don't think the OP means has the word "comment" in a cell, but is actually a comment (little red triangle @ the top right of the cell).